# Error: TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release

Tags: webpack

I am trying to webpack a sample angular app, I am getting the following error.

Followed this webpack [article](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/) and [this](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html)

> ERROR in /Users/arup.sarkar/Projects/Web/lcc-app/src/app/app.module.ts
> ./src/app/app.module.ts
> [tsl] ERROR in /Users/arup.sarkar/Projects/Web/lcc-app/src/app/app.module.ts(18,14)
> TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.

> ERROR in /Users/arup.sarkar/Projects/Web/lcc-app/src/app/app-routing.module.ts
> ./src/app/app-routing.module.ts
> [tsl] ERROR in /Users/arup.sarkar/Projects/Web/lcc-app/src/app/app-routing.module.ts(11,14)
> TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.

> ERROR in /Users/arup.sarkar/Projects/Web/lcc-app/src/app/app.component.ts
> ./src/app/app.component.ts
> [tsl] ERROR in /Users/arup.sarkar/Projects/Web/lcc-app/src/app/app.component.ts(8,14)
> TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.
> ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Those are the 3 ts files I have in my project other than main.ts. My setup is below.

> package.json in my start script

```
    "start-webpack": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "build-webpack": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail"
```

> package.json of npm versions

```
"webpack": "^4.43.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
"webpack-merge": "^5.0.9",
```

> webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
entry: {
app: './src/main.ts',
vendor: './src/vendor.ts',
polyfills: './src/polyfills.ts'
},
devtool: 'inline-source-map',
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    //use: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
    use: ['ts-loader'],
    exclude: /node_modules/,
  },
  { test: /\.css$/, use: 'css-loader' },
  { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader' },
],
},
resolve: {
extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
},
output: {
filename: 'bundle.js',
path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
},
optimization: {
splitChunks: {
  chunks: 'all',
  },
},
};
```

Comment: I do have "experimentalDecorators": true, setup in my tsconfig.json file.

Comment: i'm having the same problem.. setting in tsconfig.json is insufficient in an ng10 app that relies on custom webpack config. Trying to research if there's a webpack custom setting required. Did you figure it out already by chance?